# Missing part of an idiom or expression I heard "Have you lost the [something] you were born with"

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a story and my character is being scolded for doing something stupid. I have an expression on the tip of my tongue, but part of it keeps evading me! "Have you lost the [thing that keeps evading me] you were born with?" Is it the good senses you were born with? The brain you were born with? I can't remember and it is beginning to drive me crazy... Does anyone know the part I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is

*Have you lost the **little sense** you were born with?*

Sometimes *little* is omitted.

For examples of usage in published literature, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&ei=XLy_W9OvE8G0gger1ZDICQ&q=%22have+you+lost+the+little+sense+you+were+born+with%22&oq=%22have+you+lost+the+little+sense+you+were+born+with%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...74576.76908.0.77506.13.13.0.0.0.0.61.645.13.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.148...33i10k1.0.2sunNRY7-Gw) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&ei=rLy_W9-3IcOQ_Qbt3YMQ&q=%22have+you+lost+the+sense+you+were+born+with%22&oq=%22have+you+lost+the+sense+you+were+born+with%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...27008.28686.0.29231.7.7.0.0.0.0.76.441.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.63...33i10k1.0.KfrZfiGXjjc).

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase the 1907 American folk story [Epaminondas and His Auntie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epaminondas_and_His_Auntie), the saying is, "You don't have the **sense** you were born with."

Answer (score 0):

I think it is 'the silver spoon in the mouth' that was lost. 
If they say so, it means you're not lucky.

Comment: We say 'born with a silver spoon in the mouth' of someone from a privileged background, but we don't normally speak of losing the spoon.